# Detect file type and decode the file from Base64 format in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework, base64

How to find the file type whether it is an image or ppt or pdf from Base64 string.
How can i decode that string and also get the file extension of Base64 String.
It should be in **AngularJs**.

Answer (score 0):

If the string was obtained by FileReader.readAsDataURL() (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) it should be similar to this one:

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQg ... "
```

So the first part is the **MIME_TYPE** (data:image/jpeg;), then there's a delimitator (base64,) and finally the base64 string which can be decoded using a library like this one:

https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64

Comment: these are only for images or string,not working for pdf and docx files.

Comment: yes, it'true that [Data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme]) is mainly about images. However I've used successfully FileReader.readAsDataURL() API to convert a file of every type into a base64 string

Comment: there are many plugin and js file to encode into base64 but while decode all are giving error for docx and pdf files...